# System.Web - File does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This question is more out of curiosity than anything else. The scenario is, I put up some code to let me know if and when there were any errors in my ASP.Net intranet portal. There was absolutely no issues, it was more for being proactive than anything else, just in case.

Long story short, I added this code in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex != null) {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("a@company.com.au", "me@company.com.au");
            message.Subject = @"Error";
            message.Body = string.Format(@"<html><body>Unhandled error on: {0} <br/> {1} <br/> {2}",ex.Source.ToString(),ex.Message,ex.ToString ());
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("server.company.com.au");
            client.Send(message);
            message.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
        }
    } catch (Exception) { }
}
```

and I keep getting this error message in my email all the time:

> Unhandled error on: System.Web  File does not exist. 
>   System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist. at
>   System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String
>   virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)
>   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context, String overrideVirtualPath) at
>   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I am stumped. I have no idea where this error is coming from, I am still working on finding it. It has not effected any aspect of the site in any ways. I believe this error would have been coming up before as all I did was add the code above. I am using .Net Farmework 4.

Anybody knows what this is?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - the catch has a log to file function which I omitted from here for readability. BTW, the log file is still empty.

Comment: The possible duplicate says its the problem in dev server, mine is in the production server. dev server has no issues and dev machine has no issues either.

Comment: ...it doesn't matter the server. It is the same error, and can likely be solved the same way. You are missing a file, you just need to isolate the page that is calling it.

Comment: OK, so I copied all the .js, .css and image files (files without server side codes) from the dev machine to the production server and the error seems to have stopped, for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For all your error recording I highly recommend [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Easy to implement and it can email you when certain errors happen.

Also will save you time on creating a home-grown solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had never heard about it before. I will keep that in mind for the next time as this project is more or less insignificant and I had the error logging just for testing purposes (because this project was insignificant).

Answer (score -1):

please check your missing file or image referenced by your master page. 
To capture the error, add the following error handler to your Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    if (ex.Message == "File does not exist.")
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()), ex);
    }
}
```

some time this issue related with missing file favicon.ico

Comment: ... why throw a *new* exception when you are in the *actual* exception...?

Comment: before sending email, you can also debug this code so it will tell you the missing resource

Comment: It never gets hit in the debugger when run in my computer. Its only when it's deployed that it gives me errors.